# Messenger Chat Bot sending too many messages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-messenger

Having some problem on the chatbot that I'm currently developing it replies to messages nonstop.
I'm pretty new to this, the code below I just copied the code below to a youtube video the code is working but I'm not able to get why it was sending too many messages

```
<?php

file_put_contents("fb.txt", file_get_contents("php://input"));

$fb = file_get_contents('fb.txt');
$fb = json_decode($fb);
$sid = $fb->entry[0]->messaging[0]->sender->id;
if($sid == "105140841657941"){
    exit();
}
$data = array(
    'messaging_type' => 'RESPONSE',
   'recipient' => array('id' => "$sid"),
   'messsage' => array('text' => "Nice to Meet you")
);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode($data),
        'header' => "Content-type: application/json\n"
        )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$token = "SAMPLE TOKEN";
file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me/messages?access_token=$token", false, $context);
file_put_contents("fb.txt", "");
?>
```

Comment: Facebook will re-send requests to your webhook, if it did not respond with a 200 OK status code in the required time frame - so likely your script is not properly doing that. So you will have to do a bit of debugging, and figure out what is actually going on. Check your PHP error log for any entries relating to this first of all.

Comment: 'file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me/messages?access_token=<my token>): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'. I'm getting this error

Comment: Check what the request body contained then, there is probably a human-readable error message in there. (You have to set `ignore_errors` to true in your context options for that.)